# High-throughput viewing and selecting of photos

Tags: linux, bash

From of the thousands and thousands of personal photographs in my collection, I'd like to select some special ones to print and display as a collage. All the photos are on one hard drive but scattered around /home/$USER. I know how to find all jpg photos with a command like this: `find / -iname "*.jpg" -print`. But that only lists the file name. I could run a similar command to view the file, but that is only half the challenge.

How can I then view each photograph and also have a dialog for whether or not to copy the photo to the directory that will be printed? (For example, with `fdupes -r -d /home/$USER` I can see a dialog about which file to delete.

(Some background, I used ubuntu 12.04 x64 and I'm comfortable with the terminal.)

Comment: will a two step shell script count as a valid answer?

Comment: why this question has been down-voted?

Comment: I don't know, but I'm happy to almost have an answer!

Comment: Only wondering why you don't use Picassa. It will search your HDD for images, and with simple drag&drop you can make album with any collections. Have face recognition and more. It is free. ;) I'm not an google agent, but fpr some tasks is simply better to use the right tools. Here is the installation instructions for ubuntu:  http://www.ubuntututorials.com/install-picasa-ubuntu-12-04/ . IMHO it will be much faster selecting images with thumbnails as display each one alone... But, maybe you have some constrains what i don't know ;)

Comment: Picasa is a good suggestion and I'll think about it. It requires wine, etc, so I may try to do it with just linux first. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this problem. I personally always found e.g. qiv a nice tool for some problem like this. You can easily configure it to read a qiv-command config where you can exactly script what you want to do on a particular keypress. I use it for a similar task as you do and just keep my fingers on d (delete), space (next).

e.g.
https://bitbucket.org/ciberandy/qiv/src/3b3fb21db52c076cd05792f648df8ae659d1af92/qiv-command.example

Comment: awesome. qiv is fast and does exactly what I want to do. Also it allows to skip 5 pics, which is great when in a dull section.

Answer (score 3):

```
# assuming you have $pic_list as an array of all images
# i.e. somethiing like pic_list=`find / -iname "*.jpg"`
for pic in $pic_list
do
    display $pic &  -OR- eog $pic &
    echo "Press 'y' to copy $pic to /home/$USER/<dest_folder>"
    read option
    if [ $option = "y" -o $option = "Y" ]
    then
         cp -f $pic /home/$USER/<dest_folder>
    else
          echo "will not copy $pic"
    fi
done
```

If this is not what you are looking for, pls do let me know.

Comment: yeah! this is almost working. (1) I had to remove the parentheses in the for loop. (2) eog is working better than display, which opened files with too much zoom. (3) the only major issue is that I don't see a copy dialog. Some pics are landing in the dest_folder but I'm not sure what key combo is doing it (control+C, yes+enter, etc)... Thanks!

Comment: Thanks..I edited the answer. I never can remember `BASH syntaxes`.

Comment: So if my cursor is on the photo, then alt+f4 makes a copy and enter goes to the next photo. As far as I know...

Comment: The copy dialog should be in the terminal....you should get an interactive prompt saying something like --`do you want to copy y/n` Do you see that?

Comment: no, I don't see any dialog. I just echo $pic_list and then it's quiet.

Comment: It will not be a pop-up box...it will be in the console/terminal where you are running the script. Pls add this line between the display and cp lines -- `echo "copying $pic"` ... just for debugging.

Comment: the "copying $pic" line is NOT coming up.

Comment: that copies AND views all the pics

Comment: cool...so `&` is background operator...which I forgot, sorry. I will add that to my answer.

Comment: by "copies AND views" all the pics, I mean that it does those operations automatically and without the terminal prompt.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29426/discussion-between-bill-and-psny18)

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Make symlinks to all the images in a single directory

```
mkdir all-pics
cd all-pics
find ~/Pictures/ -iname '*.jpg' | \
     awk '{name=$0; gsub(/[/]/,"_", name);\
          system("ln -s \"" $0 "\" \"" name "\"")}'
```

*Note:* The `awk` script generates and executes the command  `ln -s "/path/to the/original image.jpg" "_path_to the_original image.jpg"` for each image found.

**2.** Use `geeqie` to view the images.

**3.** Use `Ctrl+C` shortcut to copy the current image to a separate *`to_be_printed/`* folder.  `geeqie`'s copy dialog remembers the last selected folder, so you'd only be pressing `Ctrl+C`, `Enter` to copy the picture.